# No Audio Dell XPS 9700 Kernel 5.12

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, dell

I am using a laptop Dell XPS 17. After update my Linux kernel to 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic the only available audio output device is Dummy-output. So basically linux stop recognizing my audio card. Please your help.

> $ inxi -SMA

```
System:    Host: pop-os Kernel: 5.12.0-051200rc7-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: N/A Distro: Pop!_OS 20.10 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 17 9700 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0P1CHN v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.6.3 date: 12/31/2020 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Comet Lake PCH cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.12.0-051200rc7-generic
```

Comment: Sorry, but we only support standard Ubuntu here. There's a POP!_OS support site somewhere...

Comment: @heynnema I believe it does not work on Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found [this post](https://blog.fts.scot/2020/07/04/dell-xps-2020-how-to-get-audio-working-on-linux/) which helped. Although sound seems to be working now I believe it doesn't perform 100% as it should but it's really close.

UPDATE
Although this brings back the sound, mic still does not work.
I also found out that I can use bluetooth speaker even if it says Dummy output as the only option in sound settings without installling anything at all.When connecting the Bluetooth speaker, sound works.Haven't tried it for mic though.(I dont have any)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to compile your own kernel somewhat like this:
https://blog.fts.scot/2020/07/04/dell-xps-2020-how-to-get-audio-working-on-linux/#comment-356

It does fully work for me (including microphone inputs) while others report that mic is still broken. It probably depends on which exact hardware you have within the XPS 9700 lineup